# Поиск подстрок без учёта регистра

Tags: javascript, jquery

Задача следующая:

Имеется входной текст, например: `Тест ,слово. Тест.Слово,тест, слово.`.

Требуется найти внутри текста слова, например: `Тест` и помечать их каким-либо html тегом. На выходе я должен получить текст с помеченными словами `тест` без учёта регистра.
Выходная строка должна выглядеть примерно так: `<string>Тест</string> ,слово. <string>Тест</string>.Слово,<string>тест</string>, слово.`.

Есть идея приводить текст к `lowerCase` или `upperCase`, и искать для каждого слова позиции в тексте (`indexOf`) плюс длину слова и оборачивать эти символы в html тег, но мне кажется это костыльными вариантом и нет уверенности что это сработает.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте регулярные выражения. В строке замены используйте `$&` для ссылки на сопоставившуюся строку. флаг `i` указывает на регистронезависимый поиск, флаг `g` определяет жадность поиска, или поиск по всей строке целиком.

```
var input = "Тест ,слово. Тест.Слово,тест, слово..";
var output = input.replace(/тест/ig, "<string>$&</string>");
```

Answer (score 2):

можно использовать [регулярные выражения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). В качестве параметров передав `g` - поиск по всей строке (глобально) и `i` - не учитывать регистр. Затем, с помощью `replace` заменить всё, что выбралось регуляркой на нужную конструкцию.

```js
var string = "Тест ,слово. Тест.Слово,тест, слово.";
var reg = new RegExp('тест', 'gi');

var result = string.replace(reg, function(str) {
  return '<strong>' + str + '</strong>'
});

console.log(result);
```